# Obtain M of N groups in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame with columns `a` and `b`. For each group in column `a`, I want to obtain `m` rows of the first `n` unique values of column `b`.

As a simple example, suppose `m` and `n` were 2 and 3, respectively. The following data set:

```
          a  b
0     hello  1
1     hello  2
2     hello  0
3     hello  1
4     hello  3
5     hello  2
6     hello  3
7     hello  0
8   goodbye  0
9   goodbye  3
10  goodbye  1
11  goodbye  0
12  goodbye  2
13  goodbye  2
14  goodbye  1
15  goodbye  3
```

would be transformed into

```
          a  b
0     hello  1
1     hello  2
2     hello  0
3     hello  1
5     hello  2
7     hello  0
8   goodbye  0
9   goodbye  3
10  goodbye  1
11  goodbye  0
14  goodbye  1
15  goodbye  3
```

For each group in column `a`, there are now <= 2 (`m`) instances of the first 3 (`n`) unique values of column `b`.

I am hoping for a more elegant `groupby` solution than I have come up with. My solution uses two calls to `groupby` followed by masking and concatenating the result, which *at best* is difficult to read and understand.

```
In [1]: import pandas

In [2]: m = 2

In [3]: n = 5

In [4]: import random

In [5]: a = (['hello'] * 50) + (['goodbye'] * 50)

In [6]: b = list(range(10)) * 10

In [7]: random.shuffle(b)

In [8]: random.shuffle(a)

In [9]: df = pandas.DataFrame({'a': a, 'b': b})

# Ugly and un-elegant one-liner...
In [10]: pandas.concat(x[x.b.isin(x.b.unique()[:n])] for _, x in df.groupby(['a', 'b']).head(m).groupby('a')).sort_index()
Out[10]: 
          a  b
0     hello  5
1   goodbye  2
2     hello  8
3     hello  7
4     hello  4
5     hello  9
6     hello  7
7   goodbye  5
8   goodbye  8
9   goodbye  5
10  goodbye  0
11  goodbye  2
12  goodbye  3
16  goodbye  0
21    hello  9
22    hello  8
24  goodbye  3
27    hello  5
29  goodbye  8
46    hello  4
```

Is there a cleaner method using existing `DataFrame` methods that lets me achieve what I am looking for?

Comment: I am dissatisfied with this title. Please feel free to update with a better, more descriptive title.

Comment: just to clarify, what do you mean by **first n unique values of column b** ? is it from 0-n or according to occurrence in column?

Comment: It is according to occurrence in the column.  Let me make my "simple" example more representative.

Comment: how it should behave if unique values in column b are less than **n** for particular value in column **A** ?

Comment: Then it would limited by the number of unique values in column `b`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create two conditions, one with `groupby` + `cumcount` and the other with `groupby` + `apply`(`isin` + `unique`), and then use these to index `df`.

```
m, n = 2, 3
i = df.groupby(['a', 'b']).cumcount().lt(m)
j = df.groupby('a')['b'].apply(lambda x: x.isin(x.unique()[:n]))

df[i & j]

          a  b
0     hello  1
1     hello  2
2     hello  0
3     hello  1
5     hello  2
7     hello  0
8   goodbye  0
9   goodbye  3
10  goodbye  1
11  goodbye  0
14  goodbye  1
15  goodbye  3
```

Comment: I like mask-based solutions because it enables breaking the problem into several lines.  I had attempted a solution that involved what you have for `j`, but I had a hard time with `i` because I haven't fully familiarized myself with the `GroupBy` API.  Good stuff.

Comment: @SethMMorton You're welcome. :) Although I haven't rigorously tested it, so I'm not 100% sure it's what you're looking for. Please let me know if something is amiss by any chance.

Comment: Will do. I won't be able to really try it out till i get on my work computer tomorrow. Don't think I am ignoring you till then :)

Comment: This works across all cases I have tried, including where `m` or `n` is greater than the actual amount of data that I have.